# Strapi sendmail not working. Can yout help me?

Tags: javascript, node.js, strapi

I am trying to sendmail using the strapi plugin that has this error!

```
await strapi
  .plugins['email']
  .services
  .email
  .send({
    to: 'hqkhanh@gmail.com',
    from: 'khanh@gmail.com',
    subject: 'hello',
    text: 'hello',
  });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the provider? 
Make sure you have installed **strapi-provider-email-sendgrid** or  **strapi-provider-email-nodemailer** (for latest Strapi versions)

Under your admin panel > Plugins > Email ⚙️, change your provider accordingly.

[image]

Comment: hi Niraj Ch. I am trying to custom to upload data and file for a model. But saved?
[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/95kzK.png